# How to compile Mono (mcs) in Monodevelop?

Tags: compilation, mono, monodevelop

I want to make some changes in System.Net for example.
Editing the files, and running 'make' does the job.

However, I want to add files and classes, and need reference to them. I need .sln file which can be opened via Monodevelop (I do not use MS VS), and add the files to the different csproj files.

System-bare-*.sln files opened with a lot of missing files.

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mono compilation is still make file based so you cannot use MonoDevelop yet.

Comment: Can you help me with adding files to the framework? For example I want to add foo.cs to System.Net... Where should I add foo.cs? I tried to add it everywhere. 'make -d' prompts foo.cs as prerequisite, however methods from foo aren't referenced in existing files.

Comment: In other words : How do I make changes and compile in Mono framework? (contributors to mono have a way of doing that, aren't they?..)

Comment: Learn from the closed pull requests on GitHub. They demonstrated how to properly participate in such a big project.

Comment: I've just did. Found the place.  It compiles :)  (with a little necessary  manipulation in GAC).    Thank You for your help (need 4 more points to vote for you)